# How do I gracefully fail a Service Bus triggered Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-functions

I want to use Azure Functions to call REST endpoints based on Queue messages.
[Documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-bindings-service-bus/) tells me ...

> The Functions runtime receives a message in PeekLock mode and calls Complete on the message if the function finishes successfully, or calls Abandon if the function fails.

Hence I try to fail the function by throwing an exception for the host to abandon the message when the REST call fails.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;

public static void Run(BrokeredMessage message, TraceWriter log)
{
    string body = message.GetBody<string>();

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = client.PutAsync("http://some-rest-endpoint.url/api", content).Result;
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            throw new Exception("Message could not be sent");
        }
    }    
}
```

Does anyone know a better way to gracefully fail the function?

Comment: Log the failure and call `message.Abandon()` manually

Comment: Kai, can you elaborate on what you mean by "gracefully fail the function"? The pattern you have above works well with the collaborative mode you have with Functions, where a function execution failure (which your scenario seems to be) is handled by the runtime and messages are placed in the correct state. Is there an issue with the current behavior?

Comment: With gracefully I thought about some return code or a flag in the context of the function instance which I could set. Throwing an exception is a bit hacky I guess.

Comment: Thanks @Nkosi - this seems to be the best approach for now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log the failure and call `message.Abandon()` manually

```
public static async Task RunAsync(BrokeredMessage message, TraceWriter log) {
    var body = message.GetBody<string>();

    using (var client = new HttpClient()) {
        var content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = await client.PutAsync("http://some-rest-endpoint.url/api", content);
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
            log.Warning("Message could not be sent");
            await message.AbandonAsync();
        }
    }    
}
```